# how can I set bottom in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if this is correct to set the bottom css using javascript:

```
var productElement2 = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");
productElement2.style.bottom=="0"
```

I ask this because my script does not work :p.
Thanks for the feedback :). If this is correct something else might be wrong but I just want to be sure.

Comment: WHAT DO I DO IF 2 ANSWERS ARE CORRECT ON A DIFFERENT PROBLEM???!!! AARRGGHH :p

Comment: Accept whoever gave the most complete answer. My answer, for example, only addressed one of your issues (and I was too lazy to edit to include solutions to the other ones.)

Comment: there are 2 problems and each post adresses one. there is none that is "more complete" (well now there is but not before :p). Difficult decision :p

Comment: Guffa's thoughtfulness in editing his answer should be rewarded in place of my laziness ;)

Comment: that's what i've done :). for others looking at the answers :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `=` operator for assignment. The `==` operator is for comparison.

```
productElement2.style.bottom = "0";
```

Note: If the value is a non-zero value, it needs a unit. Example:

```
productElement2.style.bottom = "10px";
```

Also, as kinakuta pointed out, the `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements, so you have to get one elements from the array. If you only have one footer, just get the first element:

```
var productElement2 = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you select the specific footer in the returned array you want to style:

```
var productElement2 = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
```

Comment: thank you for your awesome comment but it just wasn't complete enough for an "accept". :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use one equal sign.  Two is for comparison.

`productElement2.style.bottom = "0";`

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a CSS question.  The CSS style bottom: 0 will not work when position is "static" (the default in-layout position).  You would have to specify something like this CSS (with position of absolute or fixed):

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

or this code:

```
var productElement2 = document.getElementById("footer");
productElement2.style.position = "absolute";
productElement2.style.bottom = "0";
```

Also, note the single equals sign to set a variable.  You had a double equals sign which is a test of equality, not an assignment.

In addition, your `getElementsByTagName` returns an array, not a single item.   If you wanted to get a single item with a CSS id, you would use `getElementById` as I've shown here.  If you wanted to get the first item from the array returned by `getElementsByTagName`, then you'd have to reference the first item in the array rather than the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

footer should have `position:fixed` defined. Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/SSkqb/